# Centralize alert message in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to make the AlertDialog centralized. I know by default it is centralized, but when I apply some themes and styles to make the default message centralized, the alert is appearing in the top of the Window.
I followed this tutorial...
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/02/03/changing-the-style-or-theme-of-default-alertdialog-in-android/

Can we make the gravity of default alert central?

Answer (score 3):

The gravity of the default alert dialog box is at center. You are trying to make a customised alert dialog by applying the styles and themes thats why you are getting the dialog box at the top of the screen. This piece of code may help you to build a default dialog box.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)

           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Comment: I want to make the message and the title centralized with the default alertdialog, then will the above code work?

Comment: I had not tried that anyway its default dialog i think it will be a tough job to customize the default dialog box.Its better to build your own alert dialog then you will be able to customize it as u like.